# Account authenticate post method requests in python

Tags: python, python-requests

In the following code, I am trying to do POST method to microsoft online account, and I am starting with a page that requires to post an email. This is my try till now

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://moe-register.emis.gov.eg/account/login?ReturnUrl=%2Fhome%2FRegistrationForm'
headers ={
'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,ar;q=0.8',
'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
'Connection': 'keep-alive',
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
'Cookie':'__RequestVerificationToken=vdS3aPPg5qQ2bH9ADTppeKIVJfclPsMI6dqB6_Ru11-2XJPpLfs7jBlejK3n0PZuYl-CwuM2hmeCsXzjZ4bVfj2HGLs2KOfBUphZHwO9cOQ1; .AspNet.MOEEXAMREGFORM=ekeG7UWLA6OSbT8ZoOBYpC_qYMrBQMi3YOwrPGsZZ_3XCuCsU1BP4uc5QGGE2gMnFgmiDIbkIk_8h9WtTi-P89V7ME6t_mBls6T3uR2jlllCh0Ob-a-a56NaVNIArqBLovUnLGMWioPYazJ9DVHKZY7nR_SvKVKg2kPkn6KffkpzzHOUQAatzQ2FcStZBYNEGcfHF6F9ZkP3VdKKJJM-3hWC8y62kJ-YWD0sKAgAulbKlqcgL1ml6kFoctt2u66eIWNm3ENnMbryh8565aIk3N3UrSd5lBoO-3Qh8jdqPCCq38w3cURRzCd1Z1rhqYb3V2qYs1ULRT1_SyRXFQLrJs5Y9fsMNkuZVeDp_CKfyzM',
'Host': 'moe-register.emis.gov.eg',
'Origin': 'https://moe-register.emis.gov.eg',
'Referer': 'https://moe-register.emis.gov.eg/account/login?ReturnUrl=%2Fhome%2FRegistrationForm',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36'}


with requests.session() as s:
   # r = s.post(url)
    #soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

    data = {'EmailAddress': '476731809@matrouh1.moe.edu.eg'}
    r_post = s.post(url, data=data, headers=headers, verify=False)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r_post.content, 'lxml')
    print(soup)
```

What I got is the same page that requires the post of the email again. I expected to get the page that requires sign-in password..

[This](https://moe-register.emis.gov.eg/account/login?ReturnUrl=%2Fhome%2FRegistrationForm) is the starting page
and this is an example of the email that needed to be posted `476731809@matrouh1.moe.edu.eg`

** I have tried to use such a code but I got the page sign in again (although the credentials are correct)
Can you please try this code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/login'
s = requests.Session()
res = s.get('https://login.microsoftonline.com')
cookies = dict(res.cookies)
res = s.post(url, 
    auth=('476731809@matrouh1.moe.edu.eg', 'Std#050202'),
    verify=False, 
    cookies=cookies)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked out the page and following seems to be working:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'Origin': 'https://moe-register.emis.gov.eg',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_1_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
    'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
    'Referer': 'https://moe-register.emis.gov.eg/account/login',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,gl;q=0.8,fil;q=0.7,hi;q=0.6',
}

data = {
    'EmailAddress': '476731809@matrouh1.moe.edu.eg'
}

response = requests.post('https://moe-register.emis.gov.eg/account/authenticate', headers=headers, data=data, verify=False)
```

Your POST endpoint seems to be wrong, since you need to re-direct from `/login` to `/authenticate` to proceed with the request (I am on a mac so my user-agent may be different than yours/required, you can change that from the `headers` variable).

Comment: Amazing. Thank you very much. I had a look but I didn't find the sign-in part in the response. Can you help me with that point, please? I would like to enter a password on the response page. Is it possible?

Comment: The next URL is [this](https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=e6ffeec9-aee3-480d-9d60-ddbdce181893&response_type=id_token&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2fmoe-register.emis.gov.eg%2faccount%2ftrust&scope=openid%20email%20profile&response_mode=form_post&state=9c292582-c6f9-4ac1-915c-e8bf615b5ea3&nonce=314a41e0-acd0-45ea-bc81-c1213fc32cf1&login_hint=476731809@matrouh1.moe.edu.eg). Seems like the response you receive from this POST contains the parameters required for the next link. I would advice to open chrome developer console and track the HTTP requests.

Comment: The link in my above content is static, so you can just use this hard-coded link or replace the parameter in that somewhere (depending on the response you get from your POST) to change e-mail to get the login page.

Comment: I have no great experience and I am trying to get the whole process but still hard for my mind. Can you add to the code the part of adding the password to signin (and if possible putting comments to try to get the process well)??

Comment: Since the login url on microsoft page is static (login-hint parameter in the URL), I just drafted a rough request. https://pastebin.com/ff694rtn You can change your password parameter in the `data` section and remove un-necessary headers/values/cookies from the code.

Comment: Awesome. I changed the password only and in the response text I got this `Script is disabled. Click Submit to continue.`. Is there any other change that I could do in the code?

Comment: Not sure, it depends on what happens if the password is correct. You could try tracking the HTTP requests again like I said and see the headers/response of your requests.

Comment: I have updated the question. Can you please have a look at the code I put ..? Why did I get sign-in page as a response although I put the credentials?